# Как показать в модальном контроллере где я использую NSUserDefaults?! в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Как показать в модальном контроллере где я использую NSUserDefaults?!
Дело в том что сбрасывается сохранения из NSUserDefault, при открытии другого виев контроллера.. Мне сказали показать в модальном контроллере где я использую NSUserDefaults, как это сделать?

Вот код:

```
@synthesize Label;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSUserDefaults *defults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.Label.text = [defults2 objectForKey:@"SaveZapusk"];
    if ([Label.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        Label.text = 0;
        NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defults setObject:self.Label.text forKey:@"SaveZapusk"];
        [defults synchronize];
        [super viewDidLoad];
        retrun;
    }
 }

 - (IBAction) Button:(id)sender
 {
      NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
      [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
      NSNumber *number=[formatter numberFromString: Label.text];
      number=[NSNumber numberWithInt:number.intValue+1];
      Label.text=number.stringValue;
      NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      [defults setObject:self.Label.text forKey:@"SaveZapusk"];
      [defults synchronize];
}
```

Вот тут у нас загрузка счета, если счетчик загрузился пустым, то ставится 0 и сохраняется, потом идет процесс, там у нас увеличение на +1 и сохранение...

Все нормально загружается и сохраняется, но стоит перейти на другой виев контроллер через модал, то сохранение сбрасывается!

Переход я делала так: тупо поставила буттон, зажала ctrl, и протянула полоску до другого виев контроллера :) и там точно так же.

Comment: Видимо, вас попросили показать код, который написан где-то в вашем modal view controller, и который содержит работу с NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Угу, именно это я и просил

Comment: aknew, жаль тут ЛС нет) у меня не прописано в "modal view controller" ничего..

Comment: вы можете воспроизвести ситуацию на простеньком проекте или выложить сам по себе проект куда-нибудь? Без кода совершенно не ясно о чем собственно речь

Comment: Подождите, вы не знаете _свой код_? Вы не знаете, где и чем вы пользуетесь? (О боже!) Попробуйте поискать по файлам проекта.

Comment: ахах) ну я код описала в предыдущем вопросе, вот ссылка на пред. вопрос " http://hashcode.ru/questions/242834/ios-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-nsuserdefaults-%D0%B2-objective-c "

Какая разница какой код? Вот пример приведу, что уж там: ("КОД ВСТАВЛЮ В ВОПРОС")

Comment: Ну, разве в коде не видно, где вы работаете с `NSUserDefaults`[?](http://i.imgur.com/vF4kAgn.jpg)

Comment: VladD, нет, мне просто надо узнать как сделать чтоб не удалялось при открытии другого виев контроллера..) Нельзя напрямую ответить?

Comment: нельзя ответить напрямую - нету причин по которым настройки менялись бы сами собой при вызове вьюхи, что-то в вызове или в самой вьюхе не то, а вы нам его так и не показали. Кроме того меня смущает что вы используете то self.Label.text (property), то просто Label.text (ivar), но в вашей записи (@synthesize Label;) ivar будет называться _Label и судя по тому что у вас не ругается кланг, где-то имеется левая и скорее всего непроинициализированная переменная Label. По уже имеющемуся коду можно сказать что вы могли там написать что угодно

Answer (score 1):

Елена, поставьте NSLog(@"Trace: %@",)

```
[defults setObject:self.Label.text forKey:@"SaveZapusk"];
NSLog(@"Trace: %@",self.Label.text);
[defults synchronize];
```

и брекпоинты после каждого NSLog`a и посмотрите кто и где, что затирает.

Самопроизвольное затирание у NSUserDefaults может быть только при удалении приложения с устройства.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, в XCode есть Debug. Он очень полезная штука. Учитесь им пользоваться.
А по сути вопроса: в данном случае всегда выполняется условие

```
if ([Label.text isEqualToString:@""])
```

Потому что, когда вы вытаскиваете значение из NSUserDefaults коммандой

```
self.Label.text = [defults2 objectForKey:@"SaveZapusk"];
```

Вы получаете объект (id), а не текст (NSString). И в условии пытаетесь сравнить яблоки с ящиками для груш. Чтобы получить NSString используйте

self.Label.text = [defults2 stringForKey:@"SaveZapusk"];

Ссылка на документацию

Comment: сравнение такое скорее всего все равно пройдет, только если там будет не стринг может вывалить эксепшен по неизвестному селектору, а вот сам по себе if ([Label.text isEqualToString:@""]) скорее всего всегда false почему я описал в комменте к вопросу

Comment: Я сейчас создала проект, сделала там все тоже самое, и там все нормально загружается D:, видимо что-то с проектом

Comment: в xcode еть классный инструмент FileMerge, попробуйте им сравнить исходники в старом и новом проекте, он покажет в чем разница. Файл проекта не долен был дать такой эффект.

Answer (score 0):

```
     - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([defults valueForKey:@"SaveZapusk"]) {
        self.Label.text = [defults valueForKey:@"SaveZapusk"]
        }
     }

     - (IBAction) Button:(id)sender
     {
          self.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%d",[self.Label.text intValue]+1];
          NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
          [defults setObject:self.Label.text forKey:@"SaveZapusk"];
          [defults synchronize];
    }
```